# Create a geopackage file with integer attribute containing NULL values in GeoPandas

Tags: geopandas, pandas, null

I've been asked to produce a geopackage file in a specified format where one attribute is specified to be int64 nullable, and my case includes NULL values. Trying in GeoPandas, my problem is that I don't manage to create a geodataframe with a dtype=int64 containing NULL values.

I've tried adding a list of integer and None values, which becomes floats in the dataframe:

```py
>>> import geopandas as gp
>>> from shapely.geometry import Point
>>> outdf = gp.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[Point(1, 2), Point(2, 1)])
>>> outdf['nulled_int'] = [0, None]
>>> outdf['nulled_int']
0    0.0
1    NaN
Name: nulled_int, dtype: float64
```

Trying to cast it to integer gives an error:

```py
>>> outdf['nulled_int'] = outdf['nulled_int'].astype(int)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/a002001/develop/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5698, in astype
    new_data = self._data.astype(dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)
  File "/home/a002001/develop/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 582, in astype
    return self.apply("astype", dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)
  File "/home/a002001/develop/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 442, in apply
    applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
  File "/home/a002001/develop/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py", line 625, in astype
    values = astype_nansafe(vals1d, dtype, copy=True)
  File "/home/a002001/develop/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/cast.py", line 868, in astype_nansafe
    raise ValueError("Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer")
ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer
```

Starting off from a Pandas series of integer type also get casted to float automatically:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> outdf['nulled_int'] = pd.Series(dtype=int)
>>> outdf['nulled_int']
0   NaN
1   NaN
Name: nulled_int, dtype: float64
```

The geopackage format seems happy with nullable integer fields, I've made myself a small testfile with two integer attribute fields: `nulled_int` containing a null value and `integers` containing only 0 and 1:

```
$ ogrinfo riket_test.gpkg -al -geom=no -noextent -nomd
    
INFO: Open of `riket_test.gpkg'
      using driver `GPKG' successful.

[...]

nulled_int: Integer64 (0.0)
integers: Integer64 (0.0)
OGRFeature(riket_test):1
  nulled_int (Integer64) = 1
  integers (Integer64) = 1

OGRFeature(riket_test):2
  nulled_int (Integer64) = (null)
  integers (Integer64) = 0
```

Reading this file into GeoPandas ends up in the same result as in the attempts to create it above: the field containing the NULL value gets casted to float:

```py
>>> df = gp.read_file('riket_test.gpkg')
>>> df['nulled_int']
0    1.0
1    NaN
Name: nulled_int, dtype: float64
>>> df['integers']
0    1
1    0
Name: integers, dtype: int64
>>>
```

Comment: Did you try `None`?

Comment: No I had not but unfortunatly the result is the same.

Comment: I think that NaN and null do not mean the same in SQLite. See for example https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/tktview/e06c4caff3c433c80616ae5c6df63fc830825e59. Or maybe it is, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20619957/nan-in-sqlite3-have-invalid-numerical-comparisons. Try to update your NaN values into null with SQL and see what happens.

Comment: I agree, they have not the same meaning. What I should store is null rather than NaN wich is what I kind of expected while using the empty pandas series. Anyway trying to add a `None` value (which I beleave is the python equivalent to null) ends up as NaN in the dataframe.

Comment: Changing format in SQL in the generated file afterwards is ofcourse a workaround but my thought with the question was to see if it is possible within the geopandas environment.

Comment: I believe you can execute SQL with pandas https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45865608/executing-an-sql-query-over-a-pandas-dataset

Comment: I don't get either pandasql or duckdb to work on my geodataframe, both are complaining the geometry type is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

You could try converting your column to [nullable integer data type](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/integer_na.html)

```
outdf['nulled_int'] = outdf['nulled_int'].astype('Int64')
```

It will get You a bit further:

```
>> outdf
                  geometry  nulled_int
0  POINT (1.00000 2.00000)           0
1  POINT (2.00000 1.00000)        <NA>
```